# Cannot adopt UITableViewDataSource protocol - Method does not override any method from its superclass

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, protocols

I'm playing around with the `UITableView` in XCode 10.2.1 with Swift 5. [According to the Apple Developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource), adopting the `UITableViewDataSource` is the most straightforward way to populate a `UITableView` with dynamic data.

So I copied the necessary methods to override into a custom class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyDataSource : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Fetch a cell of the appropriate type.
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTypeIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell’s contents.
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Cell text"

        return cell
    }
}
```

But my code won't compile. All I get is a "Method does not override any method from its superclass" error. What? I even did used the autocomplete feature from XCode and it generated the stubs for me, yet I still cannot build my project. What is the solution?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you need the `override` before the function declaration?

Comment: I think you would override, if you subclassed `UITableViewController` but not when you conform to `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Your class' superclass is `NSObject` which does not have those table view data source methods to override in a subclass. I believe that is what that compiler is saying.

I think if you take off the `override` keyword on those function declarations that could help.